# Calling Qt MainWindow mask appears not to work when reapplied

Tags: qt

When my Qt application first starts it uses a rounded rectangle in order to mask a part of the main window. However this mask is subsequently resized, again a rounded rectangle, as the following MWE shows

```
class AppUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AppUI( QWidget *parent = 0 , Qt::WFlags flags = 0 ) : QMainWindow( parent , flags )
    {
        resize( 600 , 400 );
        QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget( this );
        setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
        setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint );

        // Create mask -- hides half of the UI
        QBitmap bitmap( this->size() );
        bitmap.clear();
        QPainter painter( &bitmap );
        painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt::black) );
        painter.setPen(QColor(Qt::black));
        painter.drawRoundedRect( 0 , 0 , 600 , 200 , 20.0f , 20.0f , Qt::AbsoluteSize );
        setMask( bitmap );
    }

    void displayEntireUi() // called after QApplication::show()
    {
        QBitmap bitmap( this->size() );
        bitmap.clear();
        QPainter painter( &bitmap );
        painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt::black) );
        painter.setPen(QColor(Qt::black));
        painter.drawRoundedRect( geometry() , 20.0f , 20.0f , Qt::AbsoluteSize );
        setMask( bitmap );  
    }

    ~AppUI(){}
};
```

The problem is that when resize is called its rounded rectangle mask no longer appears, as the following graphics show:

Application *before* resize is called (note rounded corners)
[image]

Application *after* resize is called (note lack of rounded corners)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason. `QWidget::geometry()` appears to return the size of the dimensions of the Window including the window title, borders etc. OTOH `QWidget::geometry()::size()` appears to return the width and height of the central widget which is what I want. Therefore the following change to `displayEntireUi()` appears to fix the in problem

```
QSize size = geometry().size(); 
// QSize size = this->size();   // Alternatively 
painter.drawRoundedRect( 0 , 0 , size.width() , size.height() , 20.0f , 20.0f , Qt::AbsoluteSize );
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this code inside of QMainWindow::paintEvent() handler like this

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget{
public: 
  MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent){}
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe){
     QBitmap bitmap( this->size() );
        bitmap.clear();
        QPainter painter( &bitmap );
        painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt::black) );
        painter.setPen(QColor(Qt::black));
        painter.drawRoundedRect( geometry() , 20.0f , 20.0f , Qt::AbsoluteSize );
        setMask( bitmap ); 
  }
```

See the AnalogClock example provided with Qt

Qt Documentation on [QWidget::paintEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent)